# SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE)

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have news toggle box on my webpage, where I can click a view more link, and I toggles down and displays more news.

How would I do if I want to display the latest news with one query, and with the other query display 3 other news that comes after the latest news.

I hope you understand my question!

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "latest." Do you mean the last rows added to the table or the top rows sorted by a specific column? If by a specific column, the answer to your question would probably require you to post the columns of your table.

Comment: ajax with jquery and php if you want to do it right, we dont right code for you, tell us what you  have tried and we will work off of that

Comment: It's all solved now thanks to Brian Hoover's answer!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want to use a limit statement

to get the 1st record

```
select * from table order by id desc limit 1
```

To get the 2-4th records

```
select * from table order by id desc limit 3 offset 1
```